# Javascript: Using regex to compare a domain to the email address

Tags: javascript, html

I've been trying to figure this out for a while now.  I have to use regular expression to compare a domain and email address that users input in an HTML form.  I think I have my regular expression right, but when I test my code nothing happens.
Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Chapter 7 Assignment 2</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        function domainCompare() {
            var status = false;
            var domainRegEx = new RegEx(/^[_a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+(\.[_a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+)*@ + document.myform.domain_name.value?/);
            if (document.myform.email_address.value.search(domainRegEx) == -1) {
                window.alert("Please enter an email address.");
            }
            else if (document.myform.email_address.value != domainRegEx) {
                window.alert("They do not match.");
            }
            else {
                window.alert("They match!");
                status = true;
            }
            return status;
        }
        /* ]]> */
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <center>
    <h3>Email Address Validator</h3>
    <form name="myform"> <!--onsubmit="return domainCompare();"-->
        <p>
            E-mail Domain: <input type="text" name="domain_name" size="30" />
            E-mail Address: <input type="text" name="email_address" size="30" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="domainCompare();"/>
        </p>
    </form>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, why nothing happens - you have typo in:

```
var domainRegEx = new RegEx
```

Should be:

```
var domainRegEx = new RegExp
```

Answer (score 0):

Start by changing `new RegEx` to `new RegExp`. Then you will start getting feedback.  This can be determined if you open the console and look for errors in javascript.

This is a good place to start with a regex for a domain.

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]+\.)?[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}?$/i
```